# Docker container to use host's specific network interface

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want my container to use specific ethernet card. How to define in docker-compose file to allow container to use the specific ip?

Answer (score 0):

For inbound connections, there's an optional bind-address parameter of [`ports:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports):

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.3'
    ports:
      - '10.20.30.40:5432:5432' # only listens on this host address
```

For outbound connections (as with processes running directly on the host) this is harder to directly control, and is subject to the host's usual routing rules.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just to clarify, I have two ethernet cards with one public ip on each card. What I want to do is to force docker container to use only one of the ethernet card (ip address) for communication (outbound and inbound). The thing is, I will run ftp client running in docker instance to send files.